# server.R undefined columns?

Tags: r, shiny-server, shiny

I'm trying to create a R Shiny app and have encountered the error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(dataset.temp, , input$col) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

I'm not sure what's causing this, hopefully someone could help me figure it out. Here's a sample code:

ui.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      textInput("from","Missing",
                value="Enter characters"),
      textInput("to","Missing",
                value="Enter characters"),
      selectInput("col","Select Column",
                  choices = c(1:6),
                  selected=1)),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('contents')
    )
  )
))
```

server.R

```
library(DT)
file <- read.csv("file.csv")
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
dataset.temp <- file
output$contents <- renderTable({
dataset.temp[,input$col] <- gsub(input$from,input$to,dataset.temp[,input$col])
    dataset.temp
  })
})
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: It'd help if you also provide a sample input file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a different error from running your code:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(dataset.temp, , input$col) : 
  undefined columns selected
```

The cause (at least for my error) is that `input$col` is a string and you're treating it as an integer. There are two possible fixes:

1. Change your `selectInput` to a `numericInput`, which means that now `input$col` returns an integer, or
2. Manually convert `input$col` to an integer with `col <- as.integer(input$col)`

Using the second approach, here's the complete code.

```
runApp(shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Data"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        textInput("from","Missing",
                  value="Enter characters"),
        textInput("to","Missing",
                  value="Enter characters"),
        selectInput("col","Select Column",
                    choices = c(1:6),
                    selected=1)),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput('contents')
      )
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {
    dataset.temp <- file
    output$contents <- renderTable({
        col <- as.integer(input$col)
        dataset.temp[,col] <- gsub(input$from, input$to,dataset.temp[,col])
      dataset.temp
    })
  }

))
```

I don't know what file you're using so I just used my own csv file and it works

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer! my mistake, the selectInput was meant to be column names (characters), I forgot to change it. I just changed my code from numeric values to column names:

      selectInput("col","Select Column",
                  choices = c("id","firstname"),
                  selected="id")

 and I still get the same error..could it be that we are reading in the file in different places? my file is a simple character csv file

Comment: I just tried `write.csv(iris, "file.csv")`  and then ran my code, and it still worked. See if your code works when using the iris dataset

Comment: hm it's also working for me now after I unfactor the dataset. I'll change the error message to the one you were getting as the one I was getting seem to not be reproducible. thanks for resolving this for me!